# Acessing data files through the F# Interactive in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, f#-interactive

I am developing some scripts in F#. I'm running them through the F# Interactive. I have also put some data files alongside my F# scripts. I'd like to know how to access them through code, as it seems they are not being put in an accessible way by my F# scripts. Is there some way to accomplish this without hard-coding the full data file paths?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let getDataFile name = Path.Combine(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__, name)
```

See [Source Line, File, and Path Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233234.aspx) on MSDN.